# Python serialize lexical closures?

Tags: python, serialization, closures

Is there a way to serialize a lexical closure in Python using the standard library?  pickle and marshal appear not to work with lexical closures.  I don't really care about the details of binary vs. string serialization, etc., it just has to work.  For example:

```
def foo(bar, baz) :
    def closure(waldo) :
        return baz * waldo
    return closure
```

I'd like to just be able to dump instances of closure to a file and read them back.

Edit:
One relatively obvious way that this could be solved is with some reflection hacks to convert lexical closures into class objects and vice-versa.  One could then convert to classes, serialize, unserialize, convert back to closures.  Heck, given that Python is duck typed, if you overloaded the function call operator of the class to make it look like a function, you wouldn't even really need to convert it back to a closure and the code using it wouldn't know the difference.  If any Python reflection API gurus are out there, please speak up.

Comment: Do you know how to dump *instances of ordinary module-level functions* to a file and read them back?

Comment: I'd assume you just do this with Pickle or something.  I'm in the position of being a reasonably experienced programmer, but being very new to Python, so I understand serialization and lexical closures, but very little about how Python itself works.

Comment: The only options that I know even for ordinary functions are 1. save as a source (*.py) / load using `import` (or execfile, eval, etc) 2. save as a marshalled code object (like *.pyc) / load using marshal to convert a string to code object and exec it (or eval, etc).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you simply use a class with a `__call__` method to begin with, it should all work smoothly with `pickle`.

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar, baz):
        self.baz = baz
    def __call__(self,waldo):
        return self.baz * waldo
```

On the other hand, a hack which converted a closure into an instance of a new class created at runtime would not work, because of the way `pickle` deals with classes and instances.   `pickle` doesn't store classes; only a module name and class name.  When reading back an instance or class it tries to import the module and find the required class in it.  If you used a class created on-the-fly, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 20):

PiCloud has released an open-source (LGPL) pickler which can handle function closure and a whole lot more useful stuff. It can be used independently of their cloud computing infrastructure - it's just a normal pickler.  The whole shebang is documented [here](http://docs.picloud.com/), and you can download the code via 'pip install cloud'.  Anyway, it does what you want.  Let's demonstrate that by pickling a closure:

```
import pickle
from StringIO import StringIO

import cloud

# generate a closure
def foo(bar, baz):
    def closure(waldo):
        return baz * waldo
    return closure
closey = foo(3, 5)

# use the picloud pickler to pickle to a string
f = StringIO()
pickler = cloud.serialization.cloudpickle.CloudPickler(f)
pickler.dump(closey)

#rewind the virtual file and reload
f.seek(0)
closey2 = pickle.load(f)
```

Now we have `closey`, the original closure, and `closey2`, the one that has been restored from a string serialisation. Let's test 'em.

```
>>> closey(4)
20
>>> closey2(4)
20
```

Beautiful. The module is pure python—you can open it up and easily see what makes the magic work. (The answer is a lot of code.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I got it (at least I think) -- that is, the more generic problem of pickling a function. Python is so wonderful :), I found out most of it though the dir() function and a couple of web searches. Also wonderful to have it [hopefully] solved, I needed it also.

I haven't done a lot of testing on how robust this co_code thing is (nested fcns, etc.), and it would be nice if someone could look up how to hook Python so functions can be pickled automatically (e.g. they might sometimes be closure args).

Cython module _pickle_fcn.pyx

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

cdef extern from "Python.h":
    object PyCell_New(object value)

def recreate_cell(value):
    return PyCell_New(value)
```

Python file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# author gatoatigrado [ntung.com]
import cPickle, marshal, types
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import _pickle_fcn

def foo(bar, baz) :
    def closure(waldo) :
        return baz * waldo
    return closure

# really this problem is more about pickling arbitrary functions
# thanks so much to the original question poster for mentioning marshal
# I probably wouldn't have found out how to serialize func_code without it.
fcn_instance = foo("unused?", -1)
code_str = marshal.dumps(fcn_instance.func_code)
name = fcn_instance.func_name
defaults = fcn_instance.func_defaults
closure_values = [v.cell_contents for v in fcn_instance.func_closure]
serialized = cPickle.dumps((code_str, name, defaults, closure_values),
    protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

code_str_, name_, defaults_, closure_values_ = cPickle.loads(serialized)
code_ = marshal.loads(code_str_)
closure_ = tuple([_pickle_fcn.recreate_cell(v) for v in closure_values_])
# reconstructing the globals is like pickling everything :)
# for most functions, it's likely not necessary
# it probably wouldn't be too much work to detect if fcn_instance global element is of type
# module, and handle that in some custom way
# (have the reconstruction reinstantiate the module)
reconstructed = types.FunctionType(code_, globals(),
    name_, defaults_, closure_)
print(reconstructed(3))
```

cheers, 
Nicholas

**EDIT** - more robust global handling is necessary for real-world cases. fcn.func_code.co_names lists global names.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!python

import marshal, pickle, new

def dump_func(f):
    if f.func_closure:
        closure = tuple(c.cell_contents for c in f.func_closure)
    else:
        closure = None
    return marshal.dumps(f.func_code), f.func_defaults, closure


def load_func(code, defaults, closure, globs):
    if closure is not None:
        closure = reconstruct_closure(closure)
    code = marshal.loads(code)
    return new.function(code, globs, code.co_name, defaults, closure)


def reconstruct_closure(values):
    ns = range(len(values))
    src = ["def f(arg):"]
    src += [" _%d = arg[%d]" % (n, n) for n in ns]
    src += [" return lambda:(%s)" % ','.join("_%d"%n for n in ns), '']
    src = '\n'.join(src)
    try:
        exec src
    except:
        raise SyntaxError(src)
    return f(values).func_closure




if __name__ == '__main__':

    def get_closure(x):
        def the_closure(a, b=1):
            return a * x + b, some_global
        return the_closure

    f = get_closure(10)
    code, defaults, closure = dump_func(f)
    dump = pickle.dumps((code, defaults, closure))
    code, defaults, closure = pickle.loads(dump)
    f = load_func(code, defaults, closure, globals())

    some_global = 'some global'

    print f(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Recipe 500261: Named Tuples](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/500261/) contains a function that defines a class on-the-fly. And this class supports pickling.

Here's the essence:

```
result.__module__ = _sys._getframe(1).f_globals.get('__name__', '__main__')
```

Combined with [@Greg Ball's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573569/python-serialize-lexical-closures/574789#574789) to create a new class at runtime it might answer your question.