# Decorator for Multiprocessing Lock crashes on runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Iam trying Multiprocessing and tried using Locks with decorator for ease but it crashes on run-time

```
def lock_dec(func):
    def wrapper(*args , **kwargs):
        Lock().acquire()
        func(args)
        Lock().release()

    return wrapper
```

is the decorator

```
@lock_dec
def add_no_lock(total):
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        total.value += 5
```

this is the function

```
   add_process = Process(target = add_no_lock , args = (total , ))
   add_process.start()
```

i'am getting this error but i am not able to debug the code

`Can't pickle local object 'lock_dec.<locals>.wrapper`

Comment: Pickle cannot handle closures: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573569/python-serialize-lexical-closures

In general for locking you'll also need to pass the same Lock() instance to each function that is using the lock, so calling `Lock().acquire()` and `Lock().release()` is having no effect. See the synchronization docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes

Comment: Is there any way it could work

Comment: Whoops, sorry, see my update above - you cannot use a decorator like this for locking because you'll need to pass the lock instance as an arg to the Process target function anyhow.

Comment: i was thinking of that and i tried different things but noe i get  ` The parameter is incorrect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recent post of yours drew my attention to this post. You solution is not ideal in that it does not allow arbitrary arguments to be passed to the wrapped function (right now it would not support keyword arguments). Your decorator function only needs one argument, i.e. the lock to be used, and you shouldn't care whether it is passed as a keyword argument or not. You can also simplify your code by using a context manager for the lock:

```py
from functools import wraps
from multiprocessing import Lock

def loc_dec_parent(lock=Lock()):
    def lock_dec(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args , **kwargs):
            with lock:
                func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return lock_dec

the_lock = Lock()
@loc_dec_parent(the_lock)
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    print('args:')
    for arg in args:
        print('\t', arg)
    print('kwargs:')
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        print('\t', k, '->', v)

foo(1, 2, x=3, lock=4)
```

Prints:

```
args:
         1
         2
kwargs:
         x -> 3
         lock -> 4
```

But there is still a problem with the decorator conceptually when actually used in actual multiprocessing under Windows or any platform that creates new processes using `spawn`:

```py
from functools import wraps
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process
import time

def loc_dec_parent(lock=Lock()):
    def lock_dec(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args , **kwargs):
            with lock:
                func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return lock_dec


lock = Lock()

@loc_dec_parent(lock=lock)
def foo():
    for i in range(3):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i, flush=True)

@loc_dec_parent(lock=lock)
def bar():
    for i in range(3):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i, flush=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=foo)
    p2 = Process(target=bar)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Prints:

```
0
0
1
1
2
2
```

The locking does not work! We should have seen the following it were working:

```None
0
1
2
0
1
2
```

This is because to implement the creation of each new subprocess a new Python interpreter is launched in the new process's address space and the source is re-executed from the top before control is passed to the *target* of the `Process` instance. This means that in each new process's address space a new distinct `Lock` instance is being created and the decorators are being re-executed.

The main process should be creating a single `Lock` instance which it then passes to each process as an argument. In this way you can be sure that each process is dealing with the same `Lock` instance.

**In short, a `multiprocessor.Lock` is a bad candidate for such a decorator if you wish to support all platforms.**

**Update**

To emulate Java's synchronized methods, then you should ensure that you have a single `Lock` instance that is used by all decorated functions and methods. For this you want to use a decorator implemented as a class. Also, don't forget that the wrapper function should return any possible return value that the wrapped function/method returns.

This must run on a platform using `fork` to create new processes:

```py
from functools import wraps
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process
import time

class Synchronized():
    the_lock = Lock() # class instance

    def __call__(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            with self.the_lock:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated

@Synchronized()
def foo():
    for i in range(3):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i, flush=True)

class MyClass:
    @Synchronized()
    def bar(self):
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            print(i, flush=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=foo)
    p2 = Process(target=MyClass().bar)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT after 24 hrs attempt and debugging ive found a solution by using `decorators with arguments`

```
def loc_dec_parent(*args , **kwargs):
    def lock_dec(func):
        @wraps(func)    
        def wrapper(*arg , **kwarg):
            kwargs['lock'].acquire()
            try:
                func(*arg)
            finally:
                kwargs['lock'].release()
        return wrapper
    return lock_dec
```

and function is

```
@loc_dec_parent(lock = Lock())
def add_no_lock(total):
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        total.value += 5
```

this works for me

Comment: Not for me. See my answer below.

Comment: @Booboo I think your are correct , but what i want at that time was a decorator which can make a function like a java's Synchronized Method , and that got the work done for me , or now I have bug in my code for ~3 years

Comment: Oh well. At least there are a couple of changes you can make such as supporting keyword arguments in your decorated function. Also, your decorator should return any return value returned by the decorated function. See my updated answer for Synchronized functions and methods.