# Is there a synchronization lock with key in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, synchronization, shared-resource

I need a Lock object, similar to `multiprocessing.Manager().Lock()` **which only is allowed to be released from the process which actually has acquired it.**

My manual implementation would be something similar to the following:

```
class KeyLock:
    def __init__(self):
        self._lock = Lock()
        self._key: Optional[str] = None

    def acquire(self, key: 'str', blocking: bool = True, timeout: float = 10.0) -> bool:
        if self._lock.acquire(blocking=blocking, timeout=timeout):
            self._key = key
            return True
        return False

    def release(self, key, raise_error: bool = False) -> bool:
        if self._key == key:
            self._lock.release()
            return True
        if raise_error:
            raise RuntimeError(
                'KeyLock.released called with a non matchin key!'
            )
        return False

    def locked(self):
        return self._lock.locked()
```

To create an instance of this lock and use it from multiple processes I would use a custom manager class:

```
class KeyLockManager(BaseManager):
    pass


KeyLockManager.register('KeyLock', KeyLock)

manager = KeyLockManager()
manager.start()
lock = manager.KeyLock()
```

From different processes I then can do:

```
lock.acquire(os.getpid())
# use shared ressource
...
lock.release(os.getpid())
```

This works as expected, but is seems to be a pretty big effort for a relatively simple task.
**So I wonder whether there is a easier way to do that?**

Comment: If you can convert body to a function I've created a decorator which can help you , see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57280062/11718077)

Answer (score 0):

There is `multiprocessing.RLock` that by definition can only be released by the process that acquired it. Or you might consider something like the following where the `Lock` instance is encapsulated and is meant to be only used as a context manager making it impossible to release it unless you have acquired it unless you violate the encapsulation. One, of course, could add extra protection to the class to protect attempts to violate encapsulation and get to the `Lock` instance itself. Of course, in your implementation, one could always violate encapsulation too because one can get the pid of other processes. So we assume that all the users abide by the rules.

```py
from multiprocessing import Lock

class KeyLock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__lock = Lock()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.__lock.acquire()
        return None

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.__lock.release()
        return False

# Usage:

key_lock = KeyLock()
with key_lock:
    # do something
    ...
```

Comment: Mhh - thanks @Booboo. The RLock handles the ownership of the lock as desired in the question. The problem is that the lock will be 'living' in a server process, controlled by a Manager() object. Acquiring the lock would always happen through a proxy object, thus the owner of the lock will probably always be the one from the server process.

Comment: I would advocate for the "only use the lock in the "with" context" solution. Normal locks already do this, and I don't see how this could fail unless you're inconsistent, and sometimes release the lock outside of a "with" context. It is true that using a proxy to an RLock will probably not do what you want because the actual lock object lives in only one process, which can just keep acquiring the same lock. A regular Lock however should be able to do exactly what you want with no modification.