# Can't pickle local object 'EvaluationLoop.advance.<locals>.batch_to_device' PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm trying to train a model using PyTorch Lightning.

```
trainer = pl.Trainer(
    logger = logger,
    max_epochs = N_EPOCHS,
)
     
trainer.fit(model,data_module)
```

But while doing that, I'm getting the following error after a sanity check progress bar.

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'EvaluationLoop.advance.<locals>.batch_to_device'
```

What am I doing wrong :(

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Peter, without more code, it's hard to figure out whether the same diagnosis applies to you. In my case, I had your same error-message, but Peter's solution did not fix it for me. All my kwargs were pickle-able and even avoiding save_hyperparameters as a whole did not fix it.

### Solutions

#### Solution 1

What worked was downgrading PyTorch Lightning to version ^1.7. For larger codebases, where refactoring may not be feasible, this may be a satisfactory solution.

#### Solution 2

I had this issue pop up in another project and the root cause was that I had defined a `_custom_collate` collate function in my DataModule that I was then passing as the `collate_fn` arg in the DataLoader instantiations. With multiprocessing enabled, this doesn't work, because multiprocessing relies on pickle, and python can't pickle instance methods.

So instead of using a function, I used a [callable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573569/python-serialize-lexical-closures) as suggested [here](https://shoarora.github.io/2020/02/01/collate_fn.html#dynamic-collate_fn).

In code:

This doesn't work:

```py
class DataModule(pl.LightningDataModule)
    # ...

    def collate_fn(self, incoming):
        # do stuff with incoming
        return foo(incoming)

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(
                    self.train_dataset, 
                    collate_fn=self.collate_fn
               )
```

Do this instead:

```py
class Collator:
    def __call__(incoming):
        # do stuff with incoming
        return foo(incoming)

class DataModule(pl.LightningDataModule)
    # ...

    def __init__():
        # other init stuff
        self.collator = Collator()

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(
                    self.train_dataset, 
                    collate_fn=self.collator
               )
```

Of course this solution doesn't apply only to collate functions, but any functionality needed for multiprocessing. For example I also had to do the same (wrap it in a callable object) to a transform function.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying, I figured it out. However, due to lack of code in your question, I'm not sure if it's the same for you.

My `pl.LightningModule` goes something like this:

```py
class LM(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(
        self,
        steps,
        input_shape,
        mapping,
        extrema,
        ...
        **_
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters()
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.weight_decay = weight_decay
```

I noticed that `save_hyperparameters` takes all parameters that are arguments to `__init__`, ALL of them, including `kwargs` that one often ignores in this type of setup.

## Solution

When you take these `kwargs`, you can choose to ignore them. It's a bit lazy, but I prefer this over manually having to "filter" out arguments:

```py
class LM(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(
        self,
        steps,
        input_shape,....
        reduce_lr_on_plateau_factor = 0.9,
        **kwargs
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters(ignore=kwargs.keys())
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
```

Now the warning is gone.

Comment: What if you want the kwargs to be saved? For me I've found that this bug emerges when num_workers in my dataloaders is not 0, i.e. this pickling issue emerges when multiprocessing is enabled, which is really weird. Will update here if I find the ultimate fix

Comment: I can't think of another reason for `kwargs` to be saved except for when you are using something inside `kwargs` within your model. In that case, you could opt to ignore the "unpickle-able" `kwargs` rather than all of them (or, better, add it as an positional argument).

Good luck with your bug, I haven't heard of that one before.

Comment: yep, that's what we do, ignore the unpickle-able -- perhaps there's some unpickle-ables that we aren't ignoring that are messing with multiprocessing...